# DataTable array

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to create (allocate memory) a DataTable array and then access it like that for instance:

```
dt[0].NewRow();
```

If this is possible how can I allocate memory?

Thanks,
Sun

ps I m using C# 2.0

Comment: Can you please expand on *allocate memory* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course you can:

```
int n = 10; // the number of datatables 
DataTable[] dtArray = new DataTable[n];
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    dtArray[i] = new DataTable("DataTable " + i);
```

if you don't know the number of DataTables in advance, you can use an expandable structure like a `List<DataTable>`:

```
List<DataTable> dtList = new List<DataTable>();
dtList.Add(new DataTable());
dtList.Add(new DataTable());
...
```

or, as suggested [by Reniuz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517090/datatable-array/6517148#6517148), you can use a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Why not to use [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwy42y0e.aspx) instead array?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "Sydney"; // or you could generate some random string.
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```